# Ngx-json-viewer has all json fields collapsed or none?

Tags: json, angular, angular5

I am using the ngx-json-viewer to "prettify" my json, by having collapsible fields. Below is my how I load it in:

```
<ngx-json-viewer class="" [json]="avroData" [expanded]="false"></ngx-json-viewer>
```

It works as it says, however the fields are either all collapsed or all uncollapsed. I want the user to be able to click on the exact field they want to expand, not have them all expanded immediately. Below are pictures:

This is how it looks at the start:
[image]

This is how it looks after expanded just the first 'fields' list:
[image]

I would like the nested fields inside the first "fields" to all be collapsed until the user clicks on one. Is there any way to do this with ngx-json-viewer?

I tried using json-formatter-js too but it gave some problematic dom renderings since I am not using Angularjs.

Comment: I also have the same problem.
-A
-- 1
----- 1.1
-- 2
-- 3
-----3.1
-B
-- alpha
-- beta
-- gamma

When I default it to collapse and after the component gets rendered in collapsible mode then I click to open the tree. All the leafs of the tree gets opened in one click. It should allow to navigate throw whole tree. What is happening in when I try to open node A then node 1 and 3 also gets opened.